# Azure SQL DB - Row Level Security using O365 Groups

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database, office365, row-level-security

Is it possible to set Row Level Security in an Azure SQL database using Office 365 Groups?

I have a task table in my database with an "Assigned To" (assignedTo) column. It's a varchar(255) storing an email address. It's either set to an employees email or an O365 Group. Based on the text in that column I would like to assign Row Level Security.

I need to know if assigning RLS using an O365 group is even possible? I've only been able to find posts related to Power BI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: No, I wasn't sure where to start on retrieving Azure AD or Graph in SQL